# Combine certain observations in R DataFrame

Tags: r

This seems simple, but I can't find a way to do it that seems very R like.

If you run the below code:

```
myDataFrame <- data.frame(Person = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"),
                      Age = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                      Observations = c(20, 25, 50, 45, 40, 30))

myDataFrame
```

You will see the below output:

```
> myDataFrame
  Person Age Observations
1      A   0           20
2      A   1           25
3      A   2           50
4      A   3           45
5      A   4           40
6      A   5           30
```

Bearing in mind that there are multiple people, I would like to merge the age 0 observations into the age 1 observations.

The output would then look like this:

```
> myDataFrame
  Person Age Observations
1      A   1           45
2      A   2           50
3      A   3           45
4      A   4           40
5      A   5           30
```

Any help on how to do this in an "R" like way would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We change the 0 values in 'Age' to 1 using `ifelse` within `mutate`, group by the 'Person', 'Age' columns and use `summarise` to get the `sum` of 'Observations'

```
require(dplyr)
myDataFrame <- myDataFrame %>%  
                   mutate (Age = ifelse(Age ==0, 1, Age)) %>% 
                   group_by(Person, Age) %>%
                   summarise(Observations = sum(Observations))
```

all dplyr per tip from @akrun

Comment: you could use mutate and replace within pipe to change 0 to 1

Comment: would you use some kind of conditional assignment within mutate? i.e., `mutate(Age = ifelse(Age ==0, 1, Age)`

Comment: You can use `ifelse` or `replace` i.e. `myDataFrame %>% mutate(Age= replace(Age, which(Age==0), 1)) %>% group_by(Person, Age) %>% summarise(Observations=sum(Observations))`

Comment: Changing accepted answer. Akrun's answer works fine, but takes 45.58 seconds. misspelled's answer takes 2.17. I can only assume this is due to the C++ underpinnings of dplyr? I really appreciate Akrun's answer, but felt that future readers would want to go with dplyr for the speed boost.

Comment: @Akrun - I'm sorry, I didn't specify. I've got about half a million observations over 7 variables, which I know is small potatoes for a lot of people, but it's the first time that I'm throwing "a lot" of data at R. I hear data.table is blazing, but I am already up to my neck learning base R, dplyr, ggplot2, knitr, markdown and tex.

Answer (score 3):

We change the '0' values in 'Age' column to '1' and use `aggregate` to get the `sum` of 'Observations' grouped by 'Person' and 'Age'

```
myDataFrame$Age[myDataFrame$Age==0] <- 1
aggregate(Observations~., myDataFrame, FUN=sum)
#   Person Age Observations
#1      A   1           45
#2      A   2           50
#3      A   3           45
#4      A   4           40
#5      A   5           30
```

Comment: Yeah, was thinking similarly `setDT(myDataFrame)[Age == 0L, Age := 1L][, .(Observations = sum(Observations)), by = .(Person, Age)]` but base looks more compact due to formula notation.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Feel free to post as an alternative.

Comment: I'm glad I learned dplyr right out of the gate, but at times like this, I think it may be a disadvantage. Out of curiosity, is there a slick way to do it in dplyr?

Comment: I wouldn't say my solution is slick, but it is (mostly) dplyr.